# How to differentiate between selection and save in MVC post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post

I have a form which has a DropDownList to select users and a form for user data. All controls are nested inside a form.

Cureently user DropDownList submits the form to notify about user selection to fetch appropriate data.

I want have a Button type(submit) which saves the data for the current user. Since both controls are in the same form and they both do submit, how can I differentiate if I am trying to select the user or saving the data in my action?

I have tried creating two forms as follows:

```
@model MyApp.Models.UserModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Profiles";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-switch.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="chosen.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-switch.css" />
<style type="text/css">
    .chosen-search{
        display: none;
    }
    .form-group label{
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .row{
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    th{
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()        {
    $('#CurrentUserId').chosen({placeholder_text_single: "Select a user"});
    $('#CurrentGroupId').chosen({placeholder_text_single: "Select a group"});
    $('#CurrentRoleId').chosen({placeholder_text_single: "Select a role"});

    $('#IsActive').bootstrapSwitch({
        onColor: "success",
        offColor: "danger",
        onText: "ACTIVE",
        offText: "PASSIVE",
        animate: false,
        handleWidth: 60
    });
    $('.authorizationCheckBox').bootstrapSwitch({
        onColor: "success",
        offColor: "danger",
        onText: "Y",
        offText: "N",
        animate: false,
        size: "mini"
    });
});
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Profile", "User"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="control-label">Selected user :</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="row">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CurrentUserId, new SelectList(Model.AllUsers, "Id", "Username"), "", new { @class = "form-control", onchange = @"this.form.submit();" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveProfile", "User"))
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.CurrentUser))
    {
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="row">
                @if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.UserImageUrl))
                {
                    <img src="no-user.png" class="img-circle" alt="..." style="width: 35%; display: block; margin: auto;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="display: block; margin: auto; margin-top: 10px;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Upload avatar
                    </button>
                }
                else
                {
                    <img src="@Model.UserImageUrl" class="img-circle" alt="..." style="width: 35%; display: block; margin: auto;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="display: block; margin: auto; margin-top: 10px;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-retweet"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Change avatar
                    </button>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-group" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                    <div class="switch-button xlg showcase-switch-button">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsActive)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Username :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input id="CurrentUser" name="CurrentUser" class="form-control form-control-flat" value="@Model.CurrentUser" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">E-mail :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input id="EMail" name="EMail" class="form-control form-control-flat" value="@Model.EMail" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Membership :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CurrentGroupId, new SelectList(Model.AllGroups, "Id", "Name"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Role :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CurrentRoleId, new SelectList(Model.AllRoles, "Id", "Name"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="btnSave" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 40px;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Save changes
    </button>
    }
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Profile()
{
    return View(CreateInitialUserModel());
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Profile(UserModel model)
{
    model = GetUserModel(model.CurrentUserId.Value);
    ModelState.Clear();

    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveProfile(UserModel model)
    {
        SaveModel(model)

        return RedirectToAction("Profile");
    }
```

But the problem is, at HttpPost of Profile action works well. But when I click the Save button and the HttpPost SaveProfile action is called, input parameter model does not have the values set on the screen.

Comment: Why not putting dropdown in separate form? Whole differentiation problem would disappear.

Comment: I tried that and updated my question with the structure and the results.

Comment: _input parameter model does not have the values set on the screen_ then something is wrong with data binding. Could you show how you construct user form?

Comment: Definetely there is something wroing with the data but can't figure out what. I have updated the code.

Comment: Change all `<input>` to `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Property)`. Eg. `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CurrentUser)`. You can write old plain `<input>` tags, but HTML helpers offer simpler way of creating forms.

Comment: As far as I knwo MVC binds data along name attribute of HTML elements, so I am not sure that thi is the error. Furthermore when I post back I lose the data for DropDownBoxes such as Model.AllRoles, Models.AllGroups etc. They are placed in the form and created via Html helpers as well.

Comment: Yes, it doest bind using `name`. I thought maybe there is some spelling error (binder is case sensitive), that's why I suggested HTML helpers, but since other fields are also empty, then perhaps it is not the case

Comment: Are EMail and CurrentUser fields empty on post?

Comment: use Fiddler or something similar to see what is getting passed to your `SaveProfile` action.. that's always the first thing i do when debugging mvc  forms/actions

Answer (score 0):

I would actually use two forms. Not only does it relieve your problem here, as you can just add a hidden field or something to each form to indicate which was submitted, but it prevents other issues you're likely to run into, like failing validation on any required user fields in the create form, when you just select a user, because no data was submitted for those fields.

Short of that, just use whatever JavaScript you're already using to automatically submit when an option is selected from the drop down to change a value of a hidden field or otherwise modify the post data before it's submitted.

Comment: I tried that and updated my question with the structure and the results.

Comment: Using separate forms doesn't mean using separate *actions*.

Comment: If I use the same action they both fall to same action. What will I do? Fetch single user data or update current user's data?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jquery for data retrieval? You could switch you dropdown to instead call a jquery function that performs an ajax call to a controller method that retrieves the relevant user data. Then, you can bind the data to the appropriate fields on the page using jquery. You would then only have one submit button on your view, handled through the normal mvc form process.

Comment: Let's say I am trying to avioid using jQuery at this example.

Comment: Well, another option would be to add a hidden field within the forms, as others have mentioned, or include and extra parameter in your route values object of the Html.BeginForm. Then you can use the single controller method by adding an optional parameter, which you can perform checks on in order to decide whether you want to retrieve user data, or save user data.

Answer (score -1):

-in drop downdown list change event ,you should store UserID to a variable like global variable or hiddenfields.
-Create a Button

in function=

```
function submitvalues()
{

//get stored userID here from variable 

//perform submit here

}
```